# How to use checkboxes inside TDBGrid to select multiple records?

Tags: delphi, checkbox, delphi-7, dbgrid

How to use checkboxes inside a standard TDBGrid to select multiple records? Or perhaps, do you have any recommendation for a free/open source sister of DBGrid that allows anyone to do that *easily*?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Nevermind, I found [Mike Shkolnik's SMDBGrid](http://www.scalabium.com/smdbgrid.htm) from a thread about [Delphi free & open source components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139684/delphi-free-and-open-source-components-that-are-still-maintained). This is exactly what I'm looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check this product, although this is not open-source or free, but is a great look and feel for the UI.

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumGrid/